# How do i make the generate button generate the array values at a random order?

Tags: java, arrays, string, random

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Generator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String[] gamesL = new String[] {"Dota 2", "Garrys mod", "Dungeon Defenders"};

    Random rand = new Random();

    public Generator() {
        initComponents();
    }

private void initComponents() {...}

private void generateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
display.setText("You shall play " + gamesL[0]); 
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: From the code snippet, it appears OP wants to shuffle the array and then choose the first element.  But the "possible duplicate" leads to the better solution of choosing a random number from `{0,1,2}`, and then taking that element from the array.

Answer (score 3):

use `Collections.shuffle`(your arraylist) to get the shuffled random array;
you need to import java.util.Collections.

Answer (score 0):

This unsorts an (String) array (vs. Collection)

```
public void unsortStringArray(String[] a) {
    int len = a.length;
    for(int sourceIdx = 0; sourceIdx<len; sourceIdx++) {
        int destIdx = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        String sx = a[destIdx];
        a[destIdx] = a[sourceIdx];
        a[sourceIdx] = sx;
    }
}
```